# Methods within my while Loop not working

Tags: python, loops

I'm making a simple script that looks to see if my favourite YouTuber Casey Neistat has uploaded a new video. I want the script to loop over and over so see if there is a new video or not. However, whenever I run the program it continually says that there is a new video, even though it should recognize that there has been no changes to the 'output.txt' file that contains all the links to his videos. I am very new to python and programming in general, and thus this might be a simple fix someone more experienced than I would recognize.

My code is as follows:

```
import bs4
import requests
import re

root_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'
index_url = root_url + 'user/caseyneistat/videos'

def getNeistatNewVideo():

    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.yt-lockup-thumbnail a[href^=/watch]')]


def mainLoop():

    while True:

        results = str(getNeistatNewVideo())

        past_results = str(open("output.txt"))

        if results == past_results:
            print("No new videos at this time")

            return True

        else:
            print("There is a new video!")

            print('...')
            print('Writing to new text file')
            print('...')


            f = open("output.txt", "w")
            f.write(results)

            print('...')
            print('Done writing to new text file')
            print('...')    

            return True


mainLoop()
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that `str(open('output.txt'))` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: change `str(open('output.txt'))` to `open('output.txt').read()`

Comment: That worked, thanks! Would anyone be able to inform me as to how I could get the script to loop properly? When I run it, it quits after only searching for new videos one time.

Comment: omit the `return` statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `open(output.txt)` returns a file object, not the the text within the file. Calling `str` on the file object just gives a description of the object, not the text. To get that you need to something like

```
output = open('output.txt')
past_results = output.read()
```

Also, it looks like you're calling `str` on the output of `getNeistatNewVideo` which is a list, which almost certainly not what you want to do. I guess the format of `output.txt` is a bunch of links on separate lines. If that's the case, then you would want

```
results = "\n".join(getNeistatNewVideo())
```

which would give a single string with each link on it's own line. You really should print the output of your `str` calls to see what they look like. So, the reason it always says there is something new is because

```
results == past_results
```

is always false because of the reasons outlined